# Crear conexion Postgres 9.3 con Python 3.6

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm

Estoy comenzando a programar en `Python`.
Mi primer problema es el siguiente: No puedo conectarme a la bd de `postgres`.
La libreria `psycopg2` no es detectada por el programa `pycharm`

He descargado este programa, el cual se ha instalado correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y he tratado de ejecutar este código, con su correspondiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una version de `psycopg2` para la versión 9.3 de `postgres`?... En caso de que el problema fuera este

Comment: Hola Adolfi. No sé si para Windows es igual pero en Linux yo usaba `pyscopg2` para Python 2.3, para Python 3.X estoy usando otra llamada `psycopg2-binary`. Aségurate también que al ejecutar tu aplicación estés dentro de tu ambiente virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El conector que tu has descargado es para python 3.6 y postgresql 9.6.1, esa puede ser la razón por la que no te ha funcionado.

También puedes utilizar el comando `python -m pip freeze` para ver todas las librerías que tienes instaladas y verificar que pyscopg2 esta realmente instalado.

Comment: por que es esa la razón?